# How to write an Event in Composition API (Vue3)?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I am currently having this event in a `vue3 component`:

```
<template>
    <div class="hamburger-toggle" @click="toggle" :class="{ nav__open: isActive }">
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "navbar",
  data() {
    return {
      isActive: true
    }
  },
  methods: {
    toggle: function () {
      this.isActive = !this.isActive;
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

How would I write this in the `composition api`?

Failed attempt:

```
<script>
export default {
  props: {
    isActive: false
  },
  setup(props) {
    function toggle(props) {
      props.isActive = !props.isActive;
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: In order to be able to use anything declared in `setup` in a template, you must return it from `setup`. Add this as last statement in the `setup`: `return { toggle }`

Comment: `props.isActive = !props.isActive` - props cannot be mutated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this (in composition API you use ref or reactive instead data function, and you return your functions/reactive data):

```
<template>
    <div class="hamburger-toggle" @click="toggle" :class="{ nav__open: isActive }">
</template>

<script>
import { ref } from "@vue/reactivity";
export default {
  name: "navbar",
  setup() {
    const isActive = ref(true)
    const toggle = () => {
      isActive.value = !isActive.value
    }
  return { isActive, toggle }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Also, it will work with a little less code:

```
<template>
  <div @click="isActive = !isActive"> ... </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref } from "vue";
const isActive = ref(true)
</script>
```

you can read here about the [`<script setup>`](https://blog.vuejs.org/posts/vue-3.2.html)